# TwinCAT3: Data written into .txt file has gibberish together with actual values. How do I prevent this from happening?

Tags: csv, text, encoding, plc, twincat

I am currently running a file writer function block to save data being generated from my system. The data is put into an array of strings and then using File_Write is written into a text file. However, the end result shows gibberish together with the data I want.

Image of data captured:
[Data in text file(Numbers are the date I want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVDrX.jpg)

Variable declared:

```
sData : ARRAY [0..4] OF STRING := '123','234','345','456',567';
```

File writing code I use:

```
    fbRisingEdge(CLK := bExecute);
CASE Step OF
    0 :
        IF fbRisingEdge.Q THEN
            nFileHandle := 0;
            bBusy := TRUE;
            Step := 1;
        END_IF
        
    1 :
        fbFileOpen(sPathName := sPathName, bExecute := FALSE);
        fbFileOpen(sPathName := sPathName, nMode := nMode, bExecute := TRUE);
        Step := 2;
    2 :
        fbFileOpen(bExecute := FALSE);
        IF NOT fbFileOpen.bBusy THEN
            IF fbFileOpen.bError THEN
                bError := TRUE;
                Step := 10;
            ELSE
                nFileHandle := fbFileOpen.hFile;
                Step := 3;
            END_IF
        END_IF
        
    3 :
        fbFileWrite(bExecute := FALSE);
        fbFileWrite(hFile := nFileHandle, pWriteBuff := ADR(GVL.sData), cbWriteLen := SIZEOF(GVL.sData), bExecute := TRUE);
        Step := 4;
    4 :
        fbFileWrite(bExecute := FALSE);
        IF NOT fbFileWrite.bBusy THEN
            IF fbFileWrite.bError THEN
                bError := TRUE;
                Step := 10;
            ELSE
                Step := 5;
                nBytesWritten := fbFileWrite.cbWrite;
            END_IF
        END_IF

    5 :
        fbFileClose(bExecute := FALSE);
        fbFileClose(hFile := nFileHandle, bExecute := TRUE);
        Step := 6;
    6 :
        fbFileClose(bExecute := FALSE);
        IF NOT fbFileClose.bBusy THEN
            IF fbFileClose.bError THEN
                bError := TRUE;
            END_IF
            Step := 10;
            nFileHandle := 0;
        END_IF

    10 :
        IF nFileHandle <> 0 THEN
            Step := 6;
        ELSE
            Step := 0;
            bBusy := FALSE;
        END_IF
END_CASE
```

Comment: Tell us more about `GVL.sData` - data type, structure, example values

Comment: Array of strings with 5 variables inside. Example : '123' '234' '345' '456' '567'

Comment: Put that information into your Q, together with a full type definition

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are defining `nMode` in `fbFileOpen`. You would need to have something like `nMode := FOPEN_MODEWRITE OR FOPEN_MODETEXT`.

I think that writing an array of strings in a single action could be causing your problem. You didn't specify the string length in your declaration, and the `string` datatype includes an extra byte at the end. You may want to try concatenating all of the array elements into a single string before writing.